# End/Quitting a function right after it calls another function

Tags: python, function, exit

a beginner learning python

So, suppose I have 2 functions, A n B

```py
A():
  calls B()
```

```py
B():
  usual procedures, #has return values;
```

But when a condition is met:
`B calls A();
# I want function B() to stop/quit and not return anything immediately after calling A() as a new process of A() starts

Is this possible? And safe?
Would it be possible through multithreading, which I still haven't learnt

Comment: Your B() function doesn't call A.  You need to provide more of an example, since the details of how to do this depend on what the two functions are actually trying to do.

Comment: I think you'd inevitably hit recursion errors. What's your use-case?

Comment: It might be possible, but there is probably a better approach.

Comment: agreed, even though "when a condition is met" is helpful, however it might be a good idea to illustrate for ex. a sample condition that solves recursion problem as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

What you will be building by using this pattern is a recursive call. `A` calls `B` which calls `A` which calls `B` and so on until some condition is hit where one of the two functions does a `return` (or the logic ends, but that would be strange).

Imagine:

```
def a(val):
    val = val + '->A'
    print('call stack', val)
    b(val)

    #return to the function caller
    return('finally made it out of recursion', val)

def b(val):
    if len(val) > 50:
        #finally when we reach the top of the recursion and our val variable
        # has grown to greater than 50 characters, we return. This return 
        # will propogate back up the stack to A which will finally return
        # to the caller of A
        return val
    else:
        #add to the val variable and call A, causing recursion
        val = val + '->B'
        a(val)
        
print(a('start'))
```

---

```
call stack start->A
call stack start->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
('finally made it out of recursion', 'start->A')
```

Where this isn't safe is if you end up recursing forever. That stack grows and grows until it errors with a stack overflow. What I wrote here doesn't overflow the stack because we test to make sure to stop the logic once the `val` variable is longer than 50 characters.

The other issue here is that final return only has value `start->A` for `val`. Essentially the `val` that is being printed is lost because as the stack unwinds, it doesn't propagate with a return in `b` function's `else`. Nor do we capture the return from each function call. So we have to add in some extra logic:

```
def a(val):
    val = val + '->A'
    print('call stack', val)

    #capture the return back to our val variable
    val = b(val)

    #return to the function caller
    return val

def b(val):
    if len(val) > 50:
        #finally when we reach the top of the recursion and our val variable
        # has grown to greater than 50 characters, we return. This return 
        # will propogate back up the stack to A which will finally return
        # to the caller of A
        return val
    else:
        #add to the val variable and call A, causing recursion
        val = val + '->B'
        #capture the return back to our val variable
        val = a(val)

        #return here after the recurssion ends and we get a return from function a
        return val 

print('finally made it out of recursion:', a('start'))
```

---

```
call stack start->A
call stack start->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
call stack start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
finally made it out of recursion: start->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->A
```

FWIW, this has nothing to do with multithreading, just recursion.

Comment: Sorry! I removed your original comment by Mistake!

Comment: That was me that removed it. I figured I would write out an example.

Comment: I now get it! And will try a different approach. Maybe not being lazy to pass multiple arguments will help overcome this problem. If the new approach isn't working I'll get back to you guys! (Later, Will I have to edit the same question? Or write a new one? )

Comment: Probably a good idea to write a new question. Be very specific and provide workable examples of the problem you are trying to solve so we can replicate and help guide.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate everything

Comment: Is exiting the program altogether when I'm done with it, without letting the built up return values of the recursion to return advised? And, Does this create a problem in the memory? Using os._exit(0) works with my code, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem. The memory issue with recursion is that stack build up. So as long as you've accounted for infinite loop scenarios with your logic so the stack doesn't end up hitting a memory limit, you are fine. Recursion is a pretty common solution when coding, so you aren't out in uncharted territory with this stuff.